# how do i check and uncheck input checkbox using immutable js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, immutable.js

I am trying to learn immutablejs with reactjs. I have a list of items with checkbox for each item. I want the functionality like when checkbox is clicked a checkmark should be shown and also some text like checked. I tried but when i check the first checkbox, second checkbox gets checked.

**Here is my code**

```
class AddRemoveCheckbox extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      checked: Immutable.List([])
    }
  }

  handleChange(e, key) {
    console.log('key', key);
    const { checked } = this.state;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.setState({
        checked: checked.push(key)
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({ 
        checked: checked.pop(key)
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('items');
    const { checked } = this.state;
    console.log('checked', checked.has('0'));
    const items = this.props.items.map((item,key) => {
      return (
        <li key={key} style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}>
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={checked.has(key)}
          onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e, key)} 
        />
        {item}
        </li>
        )
    })
    return (
      <div>
      Items:
      {items}
      { checked.has('0') ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddRemoveCheckbox items={['item1', 'item2'] } />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have this code on jsbin too

http://jsbin.com/fusoxos/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an Immutable Set instead of List. This lets you deal purely with values instead of messing with indices.

Your original issue was that you were `pop`ing the last item from the list, no matter what it was. You were also checking indices of the list with `has` instead of values.

constructor:

```
this.state = {
  checked: Immutable.Set()
}
```

handleChange:

```
if (e.target.checked) {
  this.setState({
    checked: checked.add(key)
  })
} else {
  this.setState({ 
    checked: checked.remove(key)
  })
}
```

render:

```
checked={checked.includes(key)}
```

and

```
  { checked.contains(0) ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked'}
```

I [forked](http://jsbin.com/gojefobido/1/edit?js,console,output) your JSBin.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the text does not change when checked.

Comment: Ah, one more line of code that needed to be changed.

Comment: i tried contains(0) but this worked only first checkbox is checked. If second checkbox is checked, i dont get checked text.

Comment: What do you want to happen with that checked text? Print if either one is checked? Then you can just check the size of the set.

Comment: Thanks i got it. I want to show checked when either on is checked. I did it using checked.size > 0. Can you please see the same question but different issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274762/could-not-check-and-uncheck-input-checkbox